# How to Populate Choices And Show NSPopUpButton in Run Time on Mac Using Swift?

Tags: swift, macos

How can I populate the choices that come up upon clicking a NSPopUpButton in run time?

I dragged NSPopUPButton to my story board, created a reference outlet from inspector to my ViewController, and connected a send action to the function that populates different choices with some if statements.

However, it doesn't seem to work. It just shows the ones I initialized when the view was loaded when I click it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The action method is called when the user selects an item. Populate the popup button before it pops up in `viewDidLoad`.